# Why run chart increasingly slow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, devexpress

First time I insert 100 point to chart, and it take about 25000 miliseconds to done load all point, 
But,next time the point from 101 to 200 take 71000 milisecons. I do not know why diffirent of time taked between 0 to 100 and 101 to 200. To slow for the next 100 point, please help me know the problem

I have tried many ways but they all seem the same, this problem is too difficult for me, here is my project.please help
https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B8uAsRdEr19GUXA4OFhvN21WZDQ

```
var dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
    dt.Tick += dt_Tick;
    dt.Start();
    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                          chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(40, 50)));
                          chart2.Series[0].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(40, 50)));
                          chart3.Series[0].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(40, 50)));
                          chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(60, 70)));
                          chart2.Series[1].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(60, 70)));
                          chart3.Series[1].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(60, 70)));
                          chart1.Series[2].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(70, 80)));
                          chart2.Series[2].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(70, 80)));
                          chart3.Series[2].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(70, 80)));
                          i++;
                   }
```

Comment: Just in case: How often is the line of code `dt.Tick += dt_Tick;` executed?

Comment: this line of code will run 300 times. If problem here, please help me know why? thanks u

Comment: Each time it runs, it adds a NEW handler to the `.Tick` event. Which means after it's run 300 times, when the `.Tick` event is raised your `dt_Tick()` method will be called 300 times. You should only run that line of code ONCE for the entire run.

Comment: How should I do to set line of code to run ONCE for the entire run. I am newbie, and very glad to see you :).
 I used thread to call event , with thread.sleep(), is it a once run in entire? But it seem this way does solve my problem, I waiting for your answer...

Comment: I can't tell for sure without seeing your code, but you should probably make the DispatcherTimer a field in your class, and initialise it when the WPF window has been created (by handing the window's Loaded event)

Comment: I have uploaded my project, I'd appreciate help any

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run the code once and NOT every 10 ms as the code above looks like why not jsut use `Dispatcher.Invoke` method:

```
 Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                          {
                             chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(40, 50)));
                             chart2.Series[0].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(40, 50)));
                             chart3.Series[0].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(40, 50)));
                             chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(60, 70)));
                             chart2.Series[1].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(60, 70)));
                             chart3.Series[1].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(60, 70)));
                             chart1.Series[2].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(70, 80)));
                             chart2.Series[2].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(70, 80)));
                             chart3.Series[2].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, rd.Next(70, 80)));
                             i++;
                          });
```

If not, then you need to explain the question better...

Comment: I have uploaded my project, I'd appreciate help any